# will spin increase the forward momentum of an object being hit in the centre of a spinning object?

Tags: kinematics

if you have scenario

A)a flat square or flat circular object, and it moves in a straight line, towards an object e.g. a ball.

vs

B)A flat square or flat circular object, moves in a straight line towards an object e.g. a ball (so same so far), but also, the flat object is spinning in the Y axis too, and the centre of the spinning flat object hits the ball. So the ball still goes straight.

Will the ball go faster or slower or same speed, in A, or B?

here is a 2min video that might help demonstrate what I mean

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aOykv3GKLSM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ball will rebound with the same speed in both cases. The relative velocity between the ball and plate at the point of contact is the same. Unlike the situation in which the ball is struck by the advancing or receding side of the spinning plate. Then the relative velocity is different.

Another way of looking at this is from the reference frame in which the plate is still spinning but the centre of the plate (or more generally, the point at which contact is made) is stationary. It is now the ball which moves towards the centre of the plate. Provided that the ball hits the centre of the plate - which is stationary in both cases - it will rebound with the same speed whether the plate is stationary or spinning.

If the collision takes place when the plate is tilted, the ball will not rebound in the direction from which it came, but the speed will still be the same.

I am assuming that the collision time is very small compared with the time it takes for the plate to make 1 revolution.